# Maintain referential integrity based on a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hierarchical `table` of locations, with a `parent/child` relationship forced via a `foreign key` and a `self join`.

The `location` has a `LocationTypeID`, which indicates what sort of location it is.

A person can only be assigned to a specific location. For example, an Office worker might have a `LocationID` which `foreign keys` to this Location table. But he can only be assigned to Locations where `LocationTypeID` relates to ID 6, which is an Office. He can't be assigned to any other ID, such as assigning him to a Building.

Is there a way to force this relationship from a database level? Maybe the only option is a `check constraint` on `Insert/Update` of both the `Location table` and `the Staff table`?

Comment: Why do you need to have a LocationTypeID in other tables? If each location has a LocationTypeID, it will be a derived field and having LocationTypeID in other tables will be redundant.

Comment: LocationTypeID is only in the Location table. LocationID is in the Staff table, and should only relate to a LocationID in the Location table WHERE the LocationTypeID = x. There's only one LocationTypeID.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't specify this type of condition on a foreign key constraint. Your best option is to use check constraints for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have over-optimized your database design. If an office worker can only be linked to an office, why do you link him to some vague "location" and not have an office table?

You say your location table is hierarchical, so you have something like 'country' -> 'city' -> 'street' -> 'building' -> 'office' or 'flat' or 'shop', and you want your officer to link to an office only.

One solution would be to provide an office table. You'd put all office location IDs in here (but still you could not really guarantee that no 'city' record gets inserted by mistake). But provided this table *is* correct, you'd link your officers to offices which link to the location table, so you could never link an officer to a non-office.

Another option involves composed keys. For example (primary keys bold):

- person_type (**person_type_no**, description) , e.g.: `1, 'officer'`
- location_type (**location_type_no**, description) , e.g. `100, 'office'`
- person_type_location_type (**person_type_no**, **location_type_no**) , e.g. `1, 100` links officer and office
- location (**location_type_no, location_no**, parent_location_type_no, parent_location_no, ...)
- person (**person_type_no, person_no**, name, ...)
- person_location (**person_type_no, person_no, location_type_no, location_no**)

A location's key is now the number plus type, so you need the two to address a record in the table. Same with a person who is identified by a number and type. Thus in the person_location table you need location number and type and person number and type to link person and location. You'd have foreign key constraints to location, person and person_type_location_type, where the latter guarantees that you can link an officer only to an office.

(It is the great advantage of composed keys over single keys to guarantee data consistency even over several levels. But it also involves some thinking to get to the right table design.)